# JQuery add html to div not working consistently

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm having issues with an ajax call to an asmx page that returns a value added to a div.
The issue is that even though I always get data back from the asmx page. The value does not get written to the div.
It's frustrating because I know it's working. But the data does not get written to the div.
And probably adding some complexity to the issue is that I'm using google maps api.

I would post the code but it's pretty big and I doubt it would fit.
but here is my ajax call.

```
function loadPropertyInfo(propertyid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PropertyViewPropertyInfo.asmx/getPropertyInfo",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'pid': '" + propertyid + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#bodyContent" + propertyid).html(msg.d);
            //alert(msg.d);
            unescape
        },
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
}
```

here is the issue. the .html part does not always write to the div.

```
$("#bodyContent" + propertyid).html(msg.d);
```

But if I uncomment the alert there is always data when the alert pops up.
however the div isn't written to.

Anyone else run into this issue?

can I do a try catch to see if the info is written to the div? and if not rerun the ajax call?

here is the code it's long.

---

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            });
            function loadPropertyInfo(propertyid) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "PropertyViewPropertyInfo.asmx/getPropertyInfo",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{'pid': '" + propertyid + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#bodyContent" + propertyid).html(msg.d);
                        //alert(msg.d);
                        unescape
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
            }
            function loadEntityInfo(propertyid) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "PropertyViewEntityInfo.asmx/getEntityInfo",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{'pid': '" + propertyid + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#propertyentityinfo" + propertyid).html(msg.d);
                        unescape
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
            }
            function AjaxSucceeded(result, propertyid) {
                //alert(result.d);
                var divid = "#propertyentityinfo" + propertyid;
                $(divid).text(result);
            }
            function AjaxFailed(result) {
                alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var mgr;
            var batch = [];
            function initialize() {
                // get the lat lon for the property
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.7367330, -80.3158520);
                // map options
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    overviewMapControl: true,
                    overviewMapControlOptions: {
                        opened: true
                    }
                };
                // map manager options
                var mgrOptions = {
                    borderPadding: 50,
                    maxZoom: 15,
                    trackMarkers: true
                };
                // setup the map
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                // start the marker manager
                mgr = new MarkerManager(map, mgrOptions);
                // drop the marker for the property
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Property",
                    zIndex: 5,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });
                var contentString = "<img id=\"image\" width=\"150\" height=\"100\" style=\"margin: 5px 0;\" src=\"http://maps.google.com/cbk?output=thumbnail&w=150&h=100&ll=25.7367330,-80.3158520\" onclick=\"streetview(25.7367330,-80.3158520)\" onerror=\"imgLoadErr(this)\" alt=\"image\" />";
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                // wait for loaded and add markers
                google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function () {
                    createMarkers(map, mgr)
                });
            }
            // create the markers for entities
            function createMarkers(map, mgr) {
                // find map bounds
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                // get the points for the properties and entities from code behind
                var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.8955829, -80.2951000);
                var marker1;
                batch.push(marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng1, map: map, icon: '/images/condominium.png', title: "Los Palacios by Miami Lakes Condo Assoc.", zIndex: 1, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
                var contentString1 = '<div id="content"><div id="siteNotice"></div><div id="bodyContent"><p>Los Palacios by Miami Lakes Condo Assoc.<br />8001 L W 6th Avenue<br />Hialeah, FL 33014<br /></p><p>Neighborhood Property Management<br />Mayra Ruiz <br />Phone: 3058192361<br /> </p><a href="PropertyView.aspx?id=6542&entitytoadd=19">Add to Property</a> </div></div>';
                var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString1 });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () { infowindow1.open(map, marker1); });
                var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.6903715, -80.3174782);
                var marker2;
                batch.push(marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng2, map: map, icon: '/images/condominium.png', title: "Kings Creek West", zIndex: 1, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
                var contentString2 = '<div id="content"><div id="siteNotice"></div><div id="bodyContent"><p>Kings Creek West<br />7695 SW 86th <br />Miami, FL 33143<br /></p><p>KW Property Management<br /><br />Phone: 3055989447<br /> </p><a href="PropertyView.aspx?id=6542&entitytoadd=20">Add to Property</a> </div></div>';
                var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString2 });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function () { infowindow2.open(map, marker2); });
                var latlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.8955829, -80.2951000);
                var marker3;
                batch.push(marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng3, map: map, icon: '/images/condominium.png', title: "Los Palacios by Miami Lakes Condo Assoc.", zIndex: 1, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
                var contentString3 = '<div id="content"><div id="siteNotice"></div><div id="bodyContent"><p>Los Palacios by Miami Lakes Condo Assoc.<br />8001 L W 6TH Avenue<br />Hialeah, FL 33014<br /></p><p>Neighborhood Property<br />Mayra Ruiz <br />Phone: 3058192361<br /> </p><a href="PropertyView.aspx?id=6542&entitytoadd=40">Add to Property</a> </div></div>';
                var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString3 });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function () { infowindow3.open(map, marker3); });
                var latlng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.6903715, -80.3174782);
                var marker4;
                batch.push(marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng4, map: map, icon: '/images/condominium.png', title: "Kings Creek West Condominiums Association", zIndex: 1, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
                var contentString4 = '<div id="content"><div id="siteNotice"></div><div id="bodyContent"><p>Kings Creek West Condominiums Association<br />7695 SW 86TH <br />Miami, FL 33143<br /></p><p>c/o KW Property Management<br />Frank Diaz <br />fduaz@kwpropertymanagement.com<br /> Phone: 3055989447<br /> </p><a href="PropertyView.aspx?id=6542&entitytoadd=44">Add to Property</a> </div></div>';
                var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString4 });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function () { infowindow4.open(map, marker4); });
                var latlng5 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.6856640, -80.3569920);
                var marker5;
                batch.push(marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng5, map: map, icon: '/images/condominium.png', title: "Puerta del Sol Condominiums Association", zIndex: 1, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
                var contentString5 = '<div id="content"><div id="siteNotice"></div><div id="bodyContent"><p>Puerta del Sol Condominiums Association<br />9972 SW 88h Street<br />Miami, FL 33176<br /></p><p>Crest Management Group<br />Nancy Messinger <br />Phone: 5619942334<br /> </p><a href="PropertyView.aspx?id=6542&entitytoadd=45">Add to Property</a> </div></div>';
                var infowindow5 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString5 });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker5, 'click', function () { infowindow5.open(map, marker5); });
                var latlng101 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.9319210, -80.2566680);
                var marker101;
                batch.push(marker101 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng101, map: map, icon: '/images/home.png', title: "092-710510 17310 NW 33 CT", zIndex: 1, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
                var contentString101 = '<div id="content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"><h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Property</h1><div id="bodyContent6545"><br /><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="wait" /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></div><div id="propertyentityinfo6545"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="wait" /></div></div>';
                var infowindow101 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString101 });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker101, 'click', function () { infowindow101.open(map, marker101); loadPropertyInfo(6545); loadEntityInfo(6545); });
                var latlng102 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.8342470, -80.2393530);
                var marker102;
                batch.push(marker102 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng102, map: map, icon: '/images/home.png', title: "092-712924 6540 NW 25 AVE", zIndex: 1, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
                var contentString102 = '<div id="content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"><h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Property</h1><div id="bodyContent6546"><br /><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="wait" /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></div><div id="propertyentityinfo6546"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="wait" /></div></div>';
                var infowindow102 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString102 });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker102, 'click', function () { infowindow102.open(map, marker102); loadPropertyInfo(6546); loadEntityInfo(6546); });
                var latlng103 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.8736080, -80.3347040);
                var marker103;
                batch.push(marker103 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng103, map: map, icon: '/images/home.png', title: "092-930413 2565 W 56TH ST 202", zIndex: 1, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
                var contentString103 = '<div id="content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"><h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Property</h1><div id="bodyContent6560"><br /><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="wait" /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></div><div id="propertyentityinfo6560"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="wait" /></div></div>';
                var infowindow103 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString103 });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker103, 'click', function () { infowindow103.open(map, marker103); loadPropertyInfo(6560); loadEntityInfo(6560); });
                // add the array to the map manager
                mgr.addMarkers(batch, 16);
                // dump markers off the map screen
                dropSuperfluousMarkers()
                // refresh
                mgr.refresh();
            }
            // remove markers that aren't currently visible
            function dropSuperfluousMarkers() {
                var alertme;
                // get the map bounds cords
                mapBounds = map.getBounds();
                // loop through the array
                for (var i = 0, ii = batch.length; i < ii; i++) {
                    if (!batch[i]) { continue };
                    if (!mapBounds.contains(batch[i].getPosition())) {
                        // remove from the map
                        batch[i].setMap(null);
                        // remove from the markers array
                        batch.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            // return if image doesn't exist
            function imgLoadErr(obj) {
                obj.alt = "Error Loading Image.\n";
                obj.alt = obj.alt + "Image does not exist in Google Maps.";
            }
            // show streetview
            function streetview(lat, lon) {
                var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
                var panoramaOptions = {
                    position: point1,
                    zoom: 0,
                    streetViewControl: true,
                    enableCloseButton: true
                };
                var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
                map.setStreetView(myPano);
                google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, 'closeclick', closeme);
                //GEvent.addListener(myPano, "error", handleNoFlash);
                document.getElementById("outerpano").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("outerpano").height = "250px";
                document.getElementById("pano").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("pano").height = "250px";
            }
            // close the streetview
            function closeme() {
                document.getElementById("outerpano").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you post what your HTML looks like.

Comment: Is there always a propertyid and does  "#bodyContent" + propertyid exist?

Comment: Chris unfortunately no. It's behind a login. The issue is that sometimes it works perfectly. and then it won't work at all.

Comment: Are you sure your selector is working correctly? Could you put some content into the div, call the selector and examine the existing html? Also, is the returned data valid HTML? If not, perhaps that's why it isn't showing in the div.

Comment: brian. yes to both. 
again the issue is that I can click on a map icon 10 time. and it will work 7 out of 10 times.
    $("#bodyContent" + propertyid).html(msg.d); 
this is not working consistently.

Comment: it looks like you are creating dynamic divs with propoertyid. could be that divs are not being added as you expect. try to log $("#bodyContent" + propertyid) and see if it exists.

Comment: here is my json return.

"<img id="image" width="150" height="100" style="margin: 5px 0;" src="http://maps.google.com/cbk?output=thumbnail&w=150&h=100&ll=25.7733275,-80.3407622" onclick="streetview(25.7733275,-80.3407622)" onerror="imgLoadErr(this)" alt="image" /><p style="margin: 0;">095-022271 <br /> 8820 FONTAINEBLEAU <br /> MIAMI, FL 33172-0000 <br /><a href="PropertyView.aspx?id=6885">Click Here</a></p>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not writing to the div but the data in msg exists then your selector `$("#bodyContent" + propertyid)` must be wrong! put an alert on that:

```
alert($("#bodyContent" + propertyid).html());
```

Or query it using Firebug, etc. Make sure your selector is correct because it seems to me, it isn't

**EDIT**
right been trawling through your code above. I believe the issue is in the line

```
infowindow100.open(map, marker100); loadPropertyInfo(6); loadEntityInfo(6);
```

this is fired on the on click event. I think the issue is that when infowindow.open is called there's a delay before it's rendered. So then when you call `loadPropertyInfo(6);` it fails because it can't find the infor window, because effectively it doesn't exist.

Two solutions,

1. Is there a call back for infowindow.open? Did have a quick look but wasn't sure?
2. wait a period of time before calling `loadPropertyInfo(6);`

try this:

```
infowindow100.open(map, marker100); setTimeout(function() {loadPropertyInfo(6); loadEntityInfo(6);}, 500);
```

**It's not pretty**, but if this solves your problem it proves my above statement.

Comment: Well the same one will work some of the time. But not work all of the time.

i can click the same one 10 times and it will work 7 out of 10 times for example.

.html(msg.d) is not consistently writing to the div.

Comment: tried your alert 

    alert($("#bodyContent" + propertyid).html()); 

Works perfectly like 5 times. Then returns null. 
could there be some network issue?

Comment: when it doesn't work can you inspect the page. My guess is that the element isn't always created? Or the other option is that it's created after your function is called

Comment: It always is created first.

And when I look at the source of the page it's there.
When you click on the map marker the div that pops up gets its content rewritten by the .html()

It's like it's half ass working.

And now that I look at it. It sometimes takes 4 to 5 seconds before it's written to the div.

Comment: I reckon infowindow.open is a async call to the Google api so there could be a delay before it renders. which would explain your inconsistent results

Comment: I've applied the setTimeout like you showed.
And I've also gone in and redone the error function. Just in case that was causing some issues.
I'm going to do some testing for a bit to see if the window results are consistent.
Cross our fingers.

Comment: After doing some testing. I think we have a winner.
Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Few things,

1. Check whether you are calling the function after document ready?
2. Place a IF condition for ajax call, make a ajax call only when propertyid is not null
3. Make sure `msg.d` is correct
4. Have try with this line of code:
   `$('#bodyContent'+propertyid).empty().html(msg.d);`

Comment: oops.
Property id is not null. I can click on the same icon several times and sometimes it works sometimes it does not work.
Very bizzare.

msg.d is fine. firebug shows it returning data.

.empty() does not help.